# What is the best way to store a huge set of objects in a file?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, serialization, deserialization

I have an application that at time can add **hundreds of thousands** of objects in a `list`(which is stored in the memory and cause outofmemory).

**I want to `serialize` the objects in a file, instead of adding it to the `list` and then deserialize when required**. But the thing is this list gets populated by a number of queries. And I don't want to keep it in memory. Instead I want to keep appending the objects in a file.

And then while writing I want to read it from the file. What is the optimal way to do it?

Comment: Use a document database.  Serialize as Java byte code?  Bad idea.  Better to go with something more modern like JSON.

Comment: @duffymo Would love to do that. But unfortunately will not be allowed to use that.

Comment: You're screwed.  Too bad.  Nothing optimal about your proposed solution: brittle, won't scale.  Hundreds of thousands of objects?  You really want an object or graph database.  Insist on it.

Comment: @duffymo Is it possible to write multiple objects in same serializable file? Not as a list, but as multiple objects.

Comment: Your way won't be thread safe.  You are going to try and reinvent something that already exists and has been implemented better than you ever will, all because of the false assumption that your solution is "simpler".

Comment: @duffymo I agree with you. But I am not allowed to use anything other than plain simple Java and a file. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not use a DB. Instead generated file using `File.createTempFile`.

Here is the sample code:

```
public class SerializeJavaDemo {
    // Just to generate some random strings
    private static final String AB = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    private static SecureRandom rnd = new SecureRandom();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SerializeJavaDemo sd = new SerializeJavaDemo();
        String prefix = "test";
        String suffix = "temp";
        File directory = new File("serialize");

        // Serialize and then read    
        try {
            File file = File.createTempFile(prefix, suffix, directory);

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            List<TestClass> list = sd.createListOfTestClasses();

            for (TestClass test : list) {
                output.writeObject(test);
            }

            output.close();
            fos.close();

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            Object obj = null;

            int count = 0;
            while (true) {
                try {
                    obj = ois.readObject();
                    if (obj == null) {
                        break;
                    }
                    if (obj instanceof TestClass) {
                        count++;
                        System.out.println(count + "." + ((TestClass) obj).toString());
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            ois.close();
            fis.close();
            file.deleteOnExit();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public List<TestClass> createListOfTestClasses() {
        List<TestClass> list = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            String name = randomString(10);
            Random r = new Random();
            Integer id = r.nextInt();
            TestClass test = new TestClass(id, name);
            list.add(test);
        }
        return list;
    }

    private String randomString(int len) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(len);
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            sb.append(AB.charAt(rnd.nextInt(AB.length())));
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

The Test class looks like:

```
public class TestClass implements Serializable {

    /**
     * Serializable id
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5574815106264956078L;

    private int id;
    private String name;

    TestClass(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() { return id; }

    public void setId(int id) { this.id = id; }

    public String getName() { return name; }

    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TestClass [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + "]";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering your response to the questions raised, 
You can use a Json serializer like Jackson. convert the Data to a List of Json Object and save it to a File.

But like others here have said already,
Not recommended.

You need to use a DB.